# When deployed from debugger, Play Services signin works, when from AppStore, it doesn't

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have been trying to find how/why, but if I debug (virtual device and physical device) the app works fine, I can do a signin, etc. If I then uninstall the app and install the version from the app store (same version of the code), I get: "There was an issue with sign in. Please try again later." dialog and no idea what's wrong.

Any suggestions on what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found whats going on.

Few steps:

1) Start qemu to launch an Android image with Play Store (clean install; Pixel 5X image will work)
2) Enable ADB Play Services logging: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/logging
-> adb shell setprop log.tag.Games VERBOSE
-> adb logcat
3) Check for messages, in my case:
01-08 05:58:25.599  7905 14197 W Auth    : [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
01-08 05:58:25.599 14204 14317 E TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE

So, UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE. I have app sigining configured and all SHA1 hashes match with what they expect under upload certificate.
For me, the url is: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=#KeyManagementPlace:p=

4) Copy the SHA1 hash under 'Certificate for App Signing'; this is the hash the app will get after Google Re-Signs it.

5) Go to Play Services details tab (for me, url is: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=#GameDetailsPlace:gt=

6) In the bottom of the page, they listed 'API Console Project'. Click the link and go to: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api?project=shades-and-hues-by-nkcss-51796 (your url will be different).

7) Go to the credentials page ( https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=shades-and-hues-by-nkcss-51796 )

8) Click: Create new Credentials -> Client OAuth -> Android -> Name (does not matter), then the SHA1 hash, and then the exact package name (check appstore url; for me it's https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nkcss.shadesandhues_agameofcolorgradients to package name would be com.nkcss.shadesandhues_agameofcolorgradients )

9) done!

The ID part will be the same as the current, so it will start working almost intantly.